# @Html.ValidationMessageFor is not working with table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following view in my MVC5 application but the problem is the Html.ValidationMessageFor helper is not working. No error message displays next to the TextBox.

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:650px;padding:40px 20px;background:#1F618D;opacity: 0.9;margin-top:30px;color:white;margin-bottom:50px;">
    <h3 style="font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;color: #ffffff;margin:5px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;opacity:0.9;">Ride Details and Change Status</h3>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <table class='table borderless'>

        <tr>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td>  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Location.LocationId, new {  id = "Location", @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:280px;background-color:#98AFC7;color:#ffffff;" })</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Customer</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Username, new { id = "CustomerUsername", @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:280px;background-color:#98AFC7;color:#ffffff;" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Destination</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Destination.LocationId, new { id = "destination", @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:280px;" })</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { id = "amount", @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:280px;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>


        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Change Status</td>
            <td><button type="button" id="changeStatusSuccessful" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" style="background-color: #10354E ;color: white;width:280px">Successful</button> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my view model

```
    [Required]
    public double Amount { get; set; }        
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public Location Destination { get; set; }

    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
```

Comment: The second parameter should be the validation message. In your case it is empty. If you want to set the error message in your view model then you only need the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount);`. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: In your model, you need to add the `ErrorMessage` attribute. You can use it like this with `Required` attribute: `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Amount is required")]`. You can also define the validation message in the view like so: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Amount, "Amount is required")`. I personally prefer decorating my model attributes with my validation logic. For example I can add a validation logic to my string variable like: `[StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "This string can be no larger than 20 characters")]`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the jQuery script *validate.js* and *validate.unobtrusive.min.js* in your view? 
Add this to the View

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am guessing this is the problem but  if it doesn't work, please provide the code generated from the view so i can help further.

Answer (score 0):

use
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}`enter code here`

and inside beginform on any label
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

and at end of label
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.{item-name}, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })